# How to create RPM for 32-bit arch from a 64-bit arch server?

Tags: centos, rhel5, centos5, rpm

Our production server is running CentOS5 64-bit arch.

Because there are no RPM available currently for SQLite latest version (v3.7.3), I created RPM using *rpmbuild* the very first time by following the instructions given [here](http://www.centos.org/modules/newbb/viewtopic.php?viewmode=flat&order=ASC&topic_id=23339&forum=38#forumpost91373).  I was able to successfully create RPM for 64-bit (x86_64) architecture.  But am not able to create RPM for 32-bit (i386) architecture.  It failed with the following errors:

```
...
...
...
+ ./configure --build=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu --target=i386-redhat-linux-gnu --program-prefix= --prefix=/usr --exec-prefix=/usr --bindir=/usr/bin --sbindir=/usr/sbin --sysconfdir=/etc --datadir=/usr/share --includedir=/usr/include --libdir=/usr/lib64 --libexecdir=/usr/libexec --localstatedir=/var --sharedstatedir=/usr/com --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --enable-threadsafe
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking for x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-gcc... no
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... 
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details.
error: Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.73141 (%build)


RPM build errors:
    Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.73141 (%build)
```

This is the command I called: `rpmbuild --target i386 -ba sqlite.spec`

My question is, how do I create RPM for 32-bit arch from a 64-bit arch server?

Answer (score 3):

```
mock -r fedora-14-i386 --rebuild foo.srpm
```

Answer (score 2):

`mock` will do a x86 build on a x86-64 system when you tell it to use a 32-bit root.

Comment: @Ignacio: Since `rpmbuild` is very new for me, I couldn't able to understand your comment.  Can you explain/expand it little bit?

Comment: `rpmbuild -bs sqlite.spec ; yum install mock ; mock .... path/to/sqlite....src.rpm` http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Projects/Mock

Comment: @Ignacio: So, in general, 32-bit arch RPM cannot be created from a server running 64-bit arch, without having `mock` installed?

Comment: Well... you can, but then you have to install 32-bit development tools and invoke it via `setarch`. It's much easier to just throw it at `mock`.

Comment: @Gnanam Mock also uses a cleanly built chroot environment to build your RPMs, so it doesn't accidentally pull in artifacts from the server it's being built on which might result in a build that differs from that you would get on a freshly installed server. I wouldn't build RPMs for production with anything else.

Answer (score 2):

Install missing 32bit lib:

```
$ sudo yum install glibc-devel.i386
```